# Modal needs to both verify fields are entered, and close upon clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a modal i'm working on that, for whatever reason, will either dismiss upon clicking submit without validating the form field inputs, or it will simply reload the form upon entering and never go away, preventing my webpage from then being seen. My idea is that this will show upon opening the webpage, the user is required to enter information into it, and then proceed to the rest of my webpage unhindered. My modal form code is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="formModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="formModalLabel">Services Contact Form</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form id="formAwesome">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">
                            First name
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="John" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">
                            Last name
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Doe" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">
                            E-mail address
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="john.doe@email.com" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="awesomeCheck">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="awesomeCheck">
                            Yes, I consent to contact.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
<style> 
#loading-img{
display:none;
}

.response_msg{
margin-top:10px;
font-size:13px;
background:#E5D669;
color:#ffffff;
width:250px;
max-width:100%;
padding:3px;
display:none;
}


    </style> 

finally with this being my ajax query:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact-form").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if($("#contact-form [name='your_name']").val() === '')
{
$("#contact-form [name='your_name']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else if ($("#contact-form [name='your_email']").val() === '')
{
$("#contact-form [name='your_email']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else
{
$("#loading-img").css("display","block");
var sendData = $( this ).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_response.php",
data: sendData,
success: function(data){
$("#loading-img").css("display","none");
$(".response_msg").text(data);
$(".response_msg").slideDown().fadeOut(3000);
$("#contact-form").find("input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea").val("");
}

});
}
});

$("#contact-form input").blur(function(){
var checkValue = $(this).val();
if(checkValue != '')
{
$(this).css("border","1px solid #eeeeee");
}
});
});

</style>
```

Again, I would like to be able to have my modal form validated upon click submit and then to close without re-opening over and over(which is currently happening). So far I have tried the following:

```
$('#CompanyProfile').modal('hide');
```

then:

```
<button type="button" id="close_btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class = "icons-office-52"></i> 
</button> 
    $("#close_btn").trigger("click");
```

then:

```
$('#closemodal').click(function() {
    $('#modalwindow').modal('hide');
});
```

and these all either JUST close the modal, or do not allow for the validation process to take place. If what i'm asking is not possible. I'd like to discuss alternatives.

Comment: I don't see an element with id of `contact-form` yet it is referenced 7 times in your javascript.

Comment: I had that thought as well, but inhereted this code from another developer. So i'm slowly reading through it for corrections. Any help would be awesome. Will change those elements to match what's in my html. Thank you @RobMoll

Comment: changed #contact-form to formModal(form id) and no change result.